# Как отслеживать попадания label в panel

Tags: c#, winforms, drag-n-drop

Объясните, как можно отслеживать `label`, когда он попадает в `panel` с `drag and drop`.
Файлы как перемещать нашел, а как это делать с внутренними объектами - пока не понятно...

Comment: Для начала. Речь идёт о WinForms, WPF?..

Comment: в WinForms не могу понять как это сделать

Comment: @Данил опишите желаемое поведение.

Comment: добавляйте обращение в виде `@username`, чтобы человек получил уведомление, о том что вы ему ответили. А иначе велики шансы, что @Streletz так и не узнает об этом

Comment: Разрешаете панели осуществлять дроп: `panel.AllowDrop = true` и обрабатываете события драга: `DragEnter` и т. п. Всё как обычно и стандартно.

Answer (score 1):

Родной поддержки Drag & Drop у Label нет, придется начинать драг руками:

```
void label1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    // позволит дропнуть текст метки в любую цель
    DoDragDrop(label1.Text, DragDropEffects.Copy);
}
```

У панели нужно выставить `AllowDrop = true` и обработать события `DragEnter` / `DragDrop`

Полный пример выглядит примерно так (обработчики нужно через свойства привязать):

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        label1.MouseDown += new MouseEventHandler(label1_MouseDown);
        panel1.AllowDrop = true; // можно выставить через свойства
        panel1.DragEnter += new DragEventHandler(panel1_DragEnter);
        panel1.DragDrop += new DragEventHandler(panel1_DragDrop);
    }

    void label1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        DoDragDrop(label1.Text, DragDropEffects.Copy);
    }

    void panel1_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.Text))
        {
            e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Copy;
        }
    }

    void panel1_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show((string)e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.Text));
    }
}
```